# Is there a way to get both the status and body when using WebClient?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I want to decide what to do after doing an HTTP request with WebClient depending on the status. I've seen some examples where people threw Mono.error() when not status OK, but when catching the exception we don't have access to the body.

I tried just returning the ClientResponse but the body is consumed once you pass the call so the body is empty. I had code similar to this:

```
WebClient client = WebClient.builder()
        .baseUrl("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com")
        .build();

ClientResponse response = client.post().uri("/posts")
        .body(BodyInserters.fromValue("{id: 101, title: 'foo', body: 'bar', userId: 1}"))
        .exchangeToMono(apiResponse -> {
            return Mono.just(apiResponse);
        })
        .block();

if (response.statusCode().equals(HttpStatus.OK)) {
    // do something
} else {
    String body = response.bodyToMono(String.class).block(); // this is empty because the body is consumed, I think
}
```

So, is there some way to just get the raw response back when using WebClient? Or should I use something else?

Answer (score 0):

I swithced to using OkHttp instead since it gave better control over the response. You can do something like this:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

String json = "{\"id\": 101, \"title\": \"foo\", \"body\": \"bar\", \"userId\": 1}";

MediaType JSON = MediaType.get("application/json; charset=utf-8");
RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(json, JSON);

Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
        .post(body)
        .build();

Call call = client.newCall(request);
Response response = call.execute();
int statusCode = response.code();
String bodyString = response.body().string();
```